# Copy field value and filter out all but the file name

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I had an issue with copying a value from one form to another via JavaScript, which I was able to figure out with help from my previous question here: "[How to copy a value from one form's file upload field to another form's text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444865/how-to-copy-a-value-from-one-forms-file-upload-field-to-another-forms-text-fie)"

So, thank you!

But now I have a new issue. When the form field value is copied over, in some browsers (such as IE), the field contains the local path of the field on the user's computer (i.e. "C:\Users\username\Desktop\file.png"), which obviously won't work in the URL.

So: is there a way to filter out everything but the file name itself before it's copied to the new field? Or a way to do it after the fact?

Thanks for the help!

Here is my most recent simplified code for this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    bindGroups();
});

var bindGroups = function() {
    // First copy values
    $("input[name='logofile']").val($("input[name='logoname']").val());

    // Then bind fields
    $("input[name='logoname']").change(function() {
        $("input[name='logofile']").val($(this).val());
    });
};
</script>

<form action="/current-url" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="logoname" value="1" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

<form name="create_landing_page" action="/landing-page-url/" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="logofile" />
<input type="submit" value="Generate Landing Page" /></form>
```

Comment: `var filename = $(this).val().replace(/\\/g,'/').split('/').pop();` goes for filenames and URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out, and it was simpler than I had hoped. All I had to do was change the line:

```
$("input[name='logofile']").val($(this).val());
```

to:

```
$("input[name='logofile']").val($(this).val().split('\\').pop());
```

The problem with using a variable was that I had to refresh it when the upload field changed, which wasn't hard; I refreshed the variable when the upload button was clicked. But for some reason, when I replaced `$("input[name='logoname']")` with my variable name, the value wouldn't copy over. I couldn't figure it out.

This ended up being much simpler, no variables needed. Split/pop did the job, so thanks everyone who suggested it! You pushed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a combination of split() and pop();

```
var  basename = fullFileName.split('\\').pop();
```

Note the double backslash to escape the slash; this will only fix the problem for Windows browsers, because Linux/OS X uses a slash (/) as directory separator, so might try this (untested as I'm on my iPad at the moment)

```
var basename = fullFileName;

if (indexof('\\', basename) >= 0) {
    basename = basename.split('\\').pop();
}

if (indexof('/', basename) >= 0) {
    basename = basename.split('/').pop();
}
```

Comment: Close but filenames use \ not / `fullFileName.split('\\').pop()`

Comment: @popnoodles I noticed if just after posting, however typing source code on an iPad is a major pita (autocorrect and programming don't like each other LOL) so it took me some time to complete my example LOL. Thanks for noticing though!

Comment: I can't get this to work for some reason...I feel like there must be something wrong with my syntax? Would this be right?

`var basename = ("input[name='logoname']");

$(function(){
    bindGroups();
});

var bindGroups = function() {
    // First copy values
    $("input[name='logofile']").val($basename.val());
};
// Then bind fields
    $basename.change(function() {
        $("input[name='logofile']").val($(this).val());
    });
</script>`

Comment: I think you should declare basename inside your function, something like var basename = $("input[name='logoname']").val(); ... Process the basename ... $("input[name='logofile']").val(basename);

Comment: When I try any of these solutions, the file name ends up not getting copied at all. I'm sure I must be missing something simple...maybe on the side where I copy the values or bind the fields?

Comment: Not sure I can help you with this at the moment. Try to debug the values you're getting. IMO if you're able to copy the unmodified value, you should be able to process that value before setting it as value to the other field, but I'm not at my computer right know, so can't check

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var field = $(this).val();
var index = field.lastIndexOf("\");
field = field.substr( index, field.length-index );
```